# How to remove the first element from a container class in a C++ program?

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, containers

Everytime I run a method called Loan &removeFirst () {} my program keeps on crashing. The program crashes whenever I attempt to delete the temporary Loan structure that I created. I can show some background for the container class and the code for my function:

```c
class ListOfLoans {

public:

    //default constructor allocate appropriate heap storage 
    //store elements on heap array declared like this: 
    //new Loan*[initial_size];
    ListOfLoans(int initial_size = 4) {
        elements = new Loan*[initial_size];
        numberOfElements = 0;
        capacity = initial_size;
        index = 0;
    }

    ~ListOfLoans(void) {
        cout << "Deleting \n";
        delete [] elements;
    }


    // answer the first element from the list but don't remove it
    Loan & first() const {
        if (capacity == 0) {
            cout << "Attempted on empty list. Exitting!" << endl;
            exit;
        } else {
            return *elements[0];
        }
    }

    // answer the first element from the list and remove it from the list
    // if the resulting list is more than three quarters empty release some memory
Loan & removeFirst() {
    index--;

    if (capacity == 0) {
           cout << "Attempted on empty list. Exitting!" << endl;
           exit;
    }

    if(size() < capacity/4) {  //shrink the container when 1/4 full 
      cout << "shrinking\n"; 
      Loan **temp = elements; 
      elements = new Loan*[capacity/2]; 
      for(index = (numberOfElements - 1); index >= 0; index--) {elements[index] = temp[index];}
      capacity /= 2; 
      delete [] temp; // my program crashes at this line, I want to delete the temp structure
    } 
      return first();
    }


private: 

    Loan ** elements; 
    int     numberOfElements; //number of elements in the list 
    int     capacity; //size of the available array memory 
    mutable int index; //used to help with the iteration

};
```

Comment: Are you required to create your own containers here? Otherwise, just `container.erase(container.begin());`

Answer (score 1):

When deleting an array of pointers (pointer to a pointer) you would typically do the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < capacity; ++i)
{
    delete temp[i];
}
delete [] temp;
```

Without the for loop, you will leak the memory that is in the internal pointer.

Does size() return the numberOfElements?  A concern I have here is that your for loop copies over the data from temp into elements and may be starting outside of the range of temp.  If this is the case, you could be overwriting memory which may be the source of the crash.  Why not just loop from 0 to size()?  If you want to remove the first element, then simply copy it with the following:

```
elements[index] = temp[index+1];
```

Finally, if you are removing the first element in the list, what does first() do internally?  From what I'm seeing above, it appears that you have already removed the first element, or had intended to.  If it is removed, it may be deleted by the time you are returning it, so you would need to copy that pointer locally and have your for loop to delete all elements skip the first one so that you have something still valid to return!

Comment: The code is supposed to answer the first element from the list and remove it. Also size() returns the numberOfElements(). So, should I copy the first element before I delete and then return it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide the implementation of size().  Does it just return numberOfElements?  If not, that's probably your problem.  If numberOfElements > capacity/2, your loop corrupts the heap, resulting in the crash at the end.

If size() returns numberOfElements, I see lots of problems with this code, but not the source of your crash, given the info you've provided.

Comment: size() returns the numberOfElements. Is that causing problems with Loan & removeFirst()?